# Get pointer events on a WinUI3 ColorPicker

Tags: winui-3

I'm currently implementing an undo/redo system for a WinUI3 app, and as part of this I need to differentiate two types of color changes from a [ColorPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.colorpicker?view=winui-2.8):

1. Where the user has dragged their cursor across the colour spectrum
2. Multiple individual clicks on the color spectrum

I had thought to do this by subscribing to the `PointerReleased` event of the `ColorPicker` to identify new pointer presses, but these events aren't being triggered.

Overlaying another control allows its `PointerReleased` events to be triggered, but I can't figure out how to pass the Pointer events to the underlying `ColorPicker`, even with `e.Handled = false` set for this events.

Any suggestions or alternative methods?

Comment: It's identified by [ColorPicker,ColorSpectrum](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/4c50e610e537aca92afc950c4be1ffb60c2f99d5/dev/ColorPicker/ColorPicker_v1.xaml#L236), [OnInputTargetPointerMoved](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/4c50e610e537aca92afc950c4be1ffb60c2f99d5/dev/ColorPicker/ColorSpectrum.h#L55C10-L55C35) but [it isn't exported](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/4c50e610e537aca92afc950c4be1ffb60c2f99d5/dev/ColorPicker/ColorSpectrum.idl).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by subclassing `ColorPicker` to enable passing of the mouse events:

**C#**

```
    public sealed partial class MyColourPicker : UserControl
    {
        public MyColourPicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ClickInterceptor_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Run custom code here...
            Picker.TriggerPointerReleased(sender, e);
        }
    }

    internal class CustomPicker : ColorPicker
    {
        public void TriggerPointerPressed(object _, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) => OnPointerPressed(e);
        public void TriggerPointerMoved(object _, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) => OnPointerMoved(e);
        public void TriggerPointerReleased(object _, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) => OnPointerReleased(e);
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TestApp.MyColourPicker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <local:CustomPicker x:Name="Picker" />
        <Grid
            x:Name="ClickInterceptor"
            Width="{x:Bind Picker.ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
            Height="{x:Bind Picker.ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
            Background="Transparent"
            PointerMoved="{x:Bind Picker.TriggerPointerMoved}"
            PointerPressed="{x:Bind Picker.TriggerPointerPressed}"
            PointerReleased="ClickInterceptor_PointerReleased" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```